# Is there a way to add an "index page" to a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that uses the omnibox as its main interface. As a result, some of the interactions leak into the omnibox history. clicking any of them and the browser tries to visit a page with the followiong url format:

```
chrome-extension://[EXTENSION_ID]/?q=[EXTENSION_INPUT]
```

which always results in a page-not-found error. Is there a way to define this page or otherwise deal with this problem?

Comment: You should be able to just drop an `index.html` file in the extension's directory and all requests will go to that.

Comment: @sachleen, I've already tried that. it didn't work.

Comment: @sachleen I just did a quick test to confirm and it looks like the path `/` does not imply `/index.html` for Chrome extensions, even when you type it manually into the address bar.

Comment: You could monitor the URL for a key identifier that its an omnibox style URL and then fix it to a correct URL ?

Comment: @AndrewHall I don't mind doing this. The problem is that I can't intercept a user's click on a history suggestion (at least, it's not specified in the omnibox api documentation).

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and have opened Chromium bug 151044.
You can subscribe here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151044